# How to decode multiple byte tags from asn1 encoded data

Tags: python, asn.1

Situation is something like as follows,
I have a BER encoded (hexadecimal) file , I want to decode the data as per the BER decoding
rules. Am able to decode most of the tags by using "pyasn1" , but am not able decode a special tag e.g.: `9F 1F` using this rule.

How do i decode without an error?
**Hint**: It is an "OctetString" representation of data.

**Sample Code**:

```
class MYData(univ.Set):
     tagSet = baseTagSet = tag.initTagSet(tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext,
                                          tag.tagFormatSimple, 21))
     componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
         namedtype.OptionalNamedType('SampleField', univ.OctetString().subtype(
         implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 31)))
     )
```

So, How to represent typeID of `9F1F` using pyasn1?

Answer (score 1):

I could decode your substrate with the following arrangements:

```
from pyasn1.type import univ, tag
from pyasn1.codec.ber import decoder
from pyasn1 import debug

debug.setLogger(debug.Debug('all'))

firstItem = univ.OctetString().subtype(implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 31))
secondItem = univ.OctetString().subtype(implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 32))

substrate = '\x9f\x1f\x02"\x00\x9f \x08\x01\x04\xf4\x17\x0c\xf0\x8a-'
i1, substrate = decoder.decode(substrate, asn1Spec=firstItem)
print i1.prettyPrint()

i2, substrate = decoder.decode(substrate, asn1Spec=secondItem)
print i2.prettyPrint()
```

That is, it looks like a concatenation of two items rather than a record-like structure.

Comment: Thanks IIya Etingof , Pooh .... Finally i decided to move with the above solutions ...

Answer (score 0):

You code works for me as-is. The 9F 1F tag looks to be just too large to fit into a single octet so it encodes into two. And since it's an IMPLICIT tag, it replaces the original tag. Other than that I see nothing special about it.

Anyway, here's my Python console:

```
>>> class MYData(univ.Set):
...      tagSet = baseTagSet = tag.initTagSet(tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext,
...                                           tag.tagFormatSimple, 21))
...      componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
...          namedtype.OptionalNamedType('SampleField', univ.OctetString().subtype(
...          implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 31)))
...      )
>>> myData = MYData()
>>> myData['SampleField'] = 'A'
>>> print myData.prettyPrint()
MYData:
 SampleField=A
>>>
>>> encoder.encode(myData)
'\xb5\x04\x9f\x1f\x01A'
>>> v, _ = decoder.decode('\xb5\x04\x9f\x1f\x01A', asn1Spec=myData)
>>> print v.prettyPrint()
MYData:
 SampleField=A
```

I'm using the latest pyasn1 version taken [from here](http://pyasn1.sourceforge.net/download.html). Please clarify what exactly does not work as expected?

Comment: My Data is exactly as follows :

Comment: My Data is exactly as follows :                         bytearray("\x9f\x1f\x02"\x00\x9f \x08\x01\x04\xf4\x17\x0c\xf0\x8a-") and i need to decode it with a single namedtype = 'Sample Field' as explained in class MYdata. So what tag should i gave to decode it in same way as it is encoded.?           Note two Tags are : "\x9f\x1f" and "\x9f  " , please note a space after second tag.